# "Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)" What causes this issue?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have been getting this area ever since I added the Interest Activity, before hand it worked fine, now I'm getting this error in logcat:

```
2019-04-10 11:51:59.045 4216-4216/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2019-04-10 11:51:59.047 4216-4216/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.foo.simplerssreader">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".InterestActivity"
            android:label="Interests"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ContactActivity"
            android:label="Contact Us"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: error is saying that you gradle has dependecy of "memtrack" module which is not actually exist in your project. try to remove "memtrack" from your gradle

Comment: I don't see anything about memtrack in either the app or project gradle

Comment: please also check your "settings.gradle" file otherwise try to invalidate cache and restart from file menu

Comment: settings gradle just has: include ':app'